# Don't get any push notifications after changing to another apple account

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications, pem

I'm currently working on an ios app. A few days ago I used an apple account which was enrolled as an individual. To receive notifications, I used fastlane pem: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/pem to create a pem file. This library generates a certificate for push notifications (Type: Apple Push Services) in your apple account. This pem file was added to our server and the push notifications worked, I received them.

However, we changed to a new apple account, which was enrolled as a individual. I used this account in XCode, created a new app id (with another bundle id then before) and provision files. I again used Fastlane pem to create a new pem file and updated the pem file on the server. For some reason I don't get notifications now. When we change to the first account and update the pem file again, it does work again. So, I guess it has something to do with the new apple account.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: seems like the generate PEM with new application id. You must be generate all new cer like distribution, development new push cer as well. coz ne app id use individule all the cer. so follow the same step what you have done for old app id with new cer

Comment: I have generated all the new files. Because with the apple account, I have a different developers portal. That way i'm sure there are new certificates. The thing is, I followed the same steps as I did with the old app.

Comment: I have to use the production certificate, right? With the type "Apple Push Services"

Answer (score 1):

Check the following:

- Is Push enabled in your Xcode-Project?
- Is Push enabled for the app in your developer Portal and is the certificate stored for push?
- Are the certificats valid? (developer portal)
- Check your notification device token what you get in the AppDelegate if it's still the same. As far as i know is the token created per device/app-combination. If your app has another id, iOS thinks it is "another" app and you will get another token.
- Did your app with the new id request remote notifications? If not you have to ask or have a look in iOS-Settings whether notefications are enabled or not.

Comment: Push is enabled in XCode (and checkmarks). Push is enabled in the developer portal (when I click on the app id), and there is a certificate with type "Apple Push Services". With valid, you mean that the expiring date has not been reached? In that case, it is valid. The device token is still the same. This is why it's weird. Everything looks okay.

Comment: Yes, i meant this.

Comment: Maybe you should remove your app from your device and reinstall it with XCode. Then the app has to ask for permission for notifications and (i think) a new device token will generated. btw: we are talking about an iPhone or iPad and not the simulator?)

Comment: Already done this. The server does get the right device token and sends notifications. I just don't see them on my phone. Besides, it works when we switch back to the other account and update the pem file.

Comment: And btw, the app with new id does ask for remote notifications.

Comment: One last thought: maybe you are using the wrong certificate? Maybe you mixed up the production and development certificates???

Comment: I have set the new bundle id, if that is what you mean?

Comment: I have to use the production certificate, right? With the type "Apple Push Services"?

Comment: You use the production for the devices, which get the app by TestFlight or the AppStore. For any other (app installed by USB und xcode) you use the development certificate.

Comment: Really? Because with the old app (old account) I used the production certificate and I got the notifications.

Comment: I think so. The last time we implemented notifications it worked as i descriped. Maybe they changed something. I'm still thinking that the notification device token is the problem. By now, i have absolutely no more idea what could be wrong. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it. I don't know what excactly caused the problem. I transfered the app on apple account 1 to apple account 2. Therefore, the app id was transferred as well. I deleted the app id I previously used on apple account 2. So I used the app id on apple account 2 that was transferred from apple account 1. The certificates were not being transferred, so I created them like I used to do and created the pem file. This did the trick.